# How can I list a index of a certain word in a sentence within a list? i dont understand how it works

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example:

```py
list = ['i like python', 'i dont like to do anything else', 'python is fun', 'i like to bowl']
```

How can I run through a list and find the word 'python' and print the index of the list containing it?

so it would print out:

```
[0,2]
```

I understand that if you have a list like:

```py
words = ['hello', 'goodbye', 'whatsup']
```

You can search for 'hello' by writing:

```py
position = words.index('hello')
print(position)
```

and it will return the index of the word. 
but I don't know how to find a word in a sentence

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
indices = [i for i,string in enumerate(list) if "python" in string]
```

Answer (score 1):

With a list comprehension:

```
[i for i in range(len(list)) if "python" in list[i]]
> [0, 2]
```

This will return the indices of the sentences that contain "python". However, if you only want to get the index if the sentence contains the *word* "python", you should split the sentence into words. Example:

```
list = ['i like python', 'ipython']
[i for i in range(len(list)) if "python" in list[i]]
> [0, 1]
[i for i in range(len(list)) if "python" in list[i].split(" ")]
> [0]
```